# Enumerating all shortest paths

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I need to find the count and enumerate ALL the shortest paths from a source node to a destination node. The edges may contain negative weights. I am unable to come up with an algorithm to do this.

Can someone help figure out how to go about this.

Answer (score -1):

There are well known algorithms for finding the shortest path. Most notably [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Only Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't like negative edges (actually negative cycles). But [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) doesn't mind them and it fairly simple to implement.

Comment: Counter-example: A-10->B-10->C. A-25->C. Now add 10 to all edges. Direct route is suddenly less expensive. Use Bellman-Ford instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

Comment: @StefanHaustein You're right. I was thinking about minimum spanning trees.

Comment: But I need to find all the shortest paths not just one shortest path. How do i do that?